# Como fazer para trazer o Model por IDS e ordernar ao mesmo tempo

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

estou com os ids retornados de uma query imensa para trazer os posts com um termo buscado... Ja esta funcionando trazer os posts atraves do Model pelos IDS selecionados mas ele traz sempre ordenado por ID e o que eu preciso eh ordenar por data... Na query imensa que fiz, ja trago os ID's ordenados corretamente mas quanto uso o modelo para buscar pelos IDS, ele desordena e traz ordenado pelo ID...
Exemplo do codigo:

```
$terms = explode(' ', Input::get('search'));
$results = 
DB::select(
    DB::raw($this->getSearchQuery($terms))
);

$postIds = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
    array_push($postIds, $result->id);
}

$posts = Post::find($postIds);
```

O problema eh na ultima linha que ao inves de buscar os IDS na ordem que eu informo, ele busca na ordenado pelo ID...

Comment: Você tentou ordenar usando `Post::find($postIds)->orderBy('data');` ?

Comment: Sim! A resposta esta logo abaixo... Acabei implementando na mao... Vi no github do proprio laravel uma issue a respeito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui ordenar da seguinte forma:

```
$postIds = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
    array_push($postIds, $result->id);
}

$posts = Post::find($postIds);

$sorted = array_flip($postIds);

foreach ($posts as $post) $sorted[$post->id] = $post;
$sorted = Collection::make(array_values($sorted));
```

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que você tenha uma lista de ids no formato array:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 8, 15, 78];

$posts = Post::whereIn($ids)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Simples e eficiente(Abre apenas uma única conexão com o banco de dados).